# How to print docstring for class attribute/element?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, docstring

I have a class:

```
class Holiday(ActivitiesBaseClass):
    """Holiday is an activity that involves taking time off work"""

    Hotel = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    """ Name of hotel """
```

I can print the class docstring by typing:

```
print(Holiday.__doc__)
```

This outputs as:

```
Holiday is an activity that involves taking time off work
```

How can I print the docstring for Hotel which is a Class attribute/element?

### What I've tried

```
print(Holiday.Hotel.__doc__)
```

returns:

```
A wrapper for a deferred-loading field. When the value is read from this object the first time, the query is executed.
```

I've also tried the `help()` function to no avail.

### N.B

Sphinx seems to be able to extract the docstrings of class attributes and include them in readthedocs so I’m hoping there’s a way

Comment: Try `help(Holiday)` in interactive mode!

Comment: There is no such thing as docstrings for attributes, it is only for classes.

Comment: Sphinx seems to be able to extract the docstrings of class attributes and include them in readthedocs so I’m hoping there’s a way

Comment: Yes, Sphinx recognizes "attribute docstrings". See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autoattribute. But as far as I know, such docstrings are ignored by the Python byte compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think it's possible to add docstring for specific field, but you can use field's [`help_text`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#help-text) argument instead:

```
Hotel = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Name of hotel")
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is currently no such implementation of attribute docstrings in Python. There was a [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0224/) that suggested implementing this functionality, but it was rejected.